# When I add a separate image to photoshop it has white background, how do I remove it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I dragged in a separate image with a transparent background, and photoshop auto-created a white background. When I go to delete it with the magic wand it says "smart object cannot be directly edited." How do I get the white parts out?

Comment: hello @samuel welcome to GDSE please try to add images for better explaination :D

Comment: no problem here with me.

Comment: To edit a smart object you need to double click it in the layers panel to open it first.  To get better help, please share screenshots showing your layers in the main document, and also when the smart object is open.

Comment: @user2650501 - when users leave comments seeking more information/screenshots, it's to help the OP, so that the problem can be narrowed down to a specific cause, which can then be answered without just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: instead of deleting the selection, go to **Layer > Layer Mask > Hide Selection**

But you have to know that:
When you drag images to an artwork, photoshop rarely creates a white background for it. Probably your original image has it.
If you really want to delete the white selection open the layers panel **Windows > Layers** then find the layer to edit and double click it. The image will open and then you can select the white area with magic wand and delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just needed that for a hobby project.